# How to create a view including the following tables?

Tags: mysql, join, view, sum

I have the following `2 tables involved`, I am trying to `create a view popularProducts`, where the `sum of each product's quantityOrdered` are equal or above 100.

I tried the following but it does't quite looks right to me:

```
SELECT productCode, productName, buyPrice, image FROM products JOIN orderDetails on products.productCode=orderDetails.products_productCode WHERE (SELECT SUM(quantityOrdered) >= 100);
```

`OrderDetails` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `orderDetails` (
  `products_productCode` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `orders_orderNumber` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `quantityOrdered` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And `products` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `productCode` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `productName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `productDescription` text,
  `quantityInStock` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `buyPrice` decimal(7,2) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  group by and having clause for the sum of quantity ordered

```
CREATE VIEW viewName AS
SELECT p.productCode, p.productName, p.buyPrice, p.image 
FROM products p
JOIN orderDetails o on p.productCode=o.products_productCode 
GROUP BY p.productCode, p.productName, p.buyPrice, p.image 
HAVING SUM(o.quantityOrdered) >= 100
```

Comment: Do I need `GROUP BY  all the columns`? Isn´t enough to `GROUP BY` just `one column` like `productName` for instance?

Comment: @codeDragon According to new release yes you need all columns that are in select list see here for more information [12.19.3 MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: Don't you need to name the `p` and `c` as aliases for intance:      
`CREATE VIEW viewName AS                                                           
SELECT p.productCode, p.productName, p.buyPrice, p.image 
FROM products AS p
JOIN orderDetails AS o on p.productCode=o.products_productCode 
GROUP BY p.productCode, p.productName, p.buyPrice, p.image 
HAVING SUM(o.quantityOrdered) >= 100;`

Comment: @codeDragon I didn't get your point can you elaborate it more ?